# Como guardar un vector en un archivo CSV. pero que los datos no se pongan en una nueva linea?

Tags: python, array, opencsv

tengo un problema sobre un vector de datos que estoy adquiriendo, el cual se esta actualizando cada cierto tiempo y necesito guardar estos números en un archivo SCV pero que los datos se agrupen continuamente y no se coloquen en una línea aparte.

El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
import csv

total = [16,16,22,33,56,45,56,89,20,33,35]

with open('Datos', 'a', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(total)
```

El problema es que los datos me los guarda en una siguiente línea y lo que requiero es que me los guarde continuamente pero no encuentro alguna instrucción para lograrlo.

Si alguien me puede ayudar, muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Quieres simplemente guardar continuamente los datos separados por comas, en una línea digamos «infinita»? En ese caso, no necesitas el módulo `csv`, sino simplemente escribir al final del fichero (ábrelo en modo añadir) y escribe los datos separados por comas como una cadena.

Answer (score 1):

No pude encontrar un método que permitiera escribir un archivo csv en una misma línea, ya que al parecer la librería csv cuenta solo con la opción writerow y writerows las cuales escriben en una nueva línea. Una cosa que puedes hacer es leer el archivo antes de escribir en él, combinando los datos del archivo con los nuevos datos y luego sobrescribir el archivo con los datos al completo. Te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

```
import os, csv

total = [16,16,22,33,56,45,56,89,20,33,35]

# Si el archivo existe adquiere los datos modificando total=[]
if os.path.exists('Datos.csv'):
    with open('Datos.csv', 'r') as fr:
        data = [int(n) for n in fr.read().split(',')]
        total = data + total

# Sobrescribe siempre la primera línea
with open('Datos.csv', 'w+', newline='') as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(fw, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(total)
```